# How to overwrite a column added to a existing csv file

Tags: python, csv, math

I have a code with add a column to a existing `csv` file. When i run it for the first time it works well but when i re-run the code it creates two new column `SupplyDelay_x` and `SupplyDelay_y` but i want it to overwrite the existing column only. Is this possible?

```
import math

supply_delay = abs(purchase_data['DeliveryDate'] - purchase_data['Date'])
SupplyDelay= pd.DataFrame({'SupplyDelay': supply_delay})
purchase_data = purchase_data.merge(SupplyDelay, left_index = True, right_index = True)
purchase_data.to_csv('Lokad_PurchaseOrders.csv')

purchase_data
```

Expected Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using merge based on the key=Supply Delay.If you want to use merge, inplace of Supply Delay use a key column.Whats currently happening is that when you first use merge the new column is created in the dataframe and on the second run another column is created using the previous column as the key therefore as the column names are same python automatically adds _x and _y after the column names.Hope it is clear where you are doing wrong

Comment: Thanks for explaining my mistake.

Comment: @pratha1995 Please mark it as a correct answer if it helped :)